# Creating consumer and temporary queue in same connection in Activemq?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, messaging

i am new to activemq. when i create a consumer for  temporary queue the consumer give a point to temporary queue that was created in the session.it will be a synchronize process.after that it will produce the message to broker(activemq).the code follows

```
// client side
 Destination tempDest = session.createTemporaryQueue();
 MessageConsumer responseConsumer = session.createConsumer(tempDest);
```

...

```
// send a request..
message.setJMSReplyTo(tempDest)
message.setJMSCorrelationID(myCorrelationID);

producer.send(message);
```

i want to know whether i can create a consumer for the  Temporary Queue  in different connection or session ?if i can then how to consume the Temporary Queue  with its name in different session or connection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably already read [here](http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html) (where you copied the example from), **temporary queues** are created per request. That means they **are not designed to be used in another session or connection**.

Comment: Actually, temporary queues can be used from different Sessions of the same connection, but not from different connections.